# preg_match_all and preg_replace foreach loop

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to convert [quote="author"]text[/quote] to a formatted div block.

`$p_text`:

```
[quote="person1"]Hello![/quote]
[quote="person2"]Hi![/quote]
```

Function:

```
function bbCode($p_text){

      $pattern = '/\[quote="(.+?)"\]/'; // matches the author name, i.e. person1
      preg_match_all($pattern, $p_text, $matches);

      $authorCounter = 0;

      foreach ($matches as $matchgroup) {

        $author = $matchgroup[$authorCounter];

        $pattern1 = '/\[quote=".+?"\]/'; // captures [quote="..."]
        $replacement1 = '<div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author">' . $author . ' wrote:</strong><br>';
        $p_text = preg_replace($pattern1, $replacement1, $p_text);

        $authorCounter++;
      }

      $pattern2 = '/\[\/quote\]/'; // captures [/quote]
      $replacement2 = '</div>';
      $p_text = preg_replace($pattern2, $replacement2, $p_text);

      return $p_text;

}
```

This is replacing both quote's authors with "person2" because the second `foreach` iteration replaces the text again(?). How could I make sure each quote has the correct person's name?

Comment: Please try my library for parsing shortcodes and BBCodes: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . If you need more information, submit an issue and I'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with just one regex. The trick is to put certain parts of the search pattern in parenthesis and refer to those parts in the replace pattern using `$1`, `$2` and so on.

```
$string = '[quote="person1"]Hello![/quote][quote="person2"]Hi![/quote]';
$output = preg_replace('/\[quote="([^"]+)"\]([^[]+)\[\/quote\]/', '<div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author">$1 wrote:</strong><br>$2</div>', $string);

echo $output;
```

Output:

```
<div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author">person1 wrote:</strong><br>Hello!</div>
<div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author">person2 wrote:</strong><br>Hi!</div>
```

Live example at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e8dd7798b29df5bd161eb01f7c11329fc13283f

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I wish I were more skilled with regex, I've only just started learning so I don't know some of the more advanced methods :\

Comment: Unfortunately some of the explanations in the php manual are not really good. Using regex is not difficult at all just examine some of the examples in the manual and use tools like http://www.regexpal.com/ to fiddle around with your regex.